# Global variable changed by multiple functions - how to declare in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I am using some variable in multiple functions.
This includes changing the variable values by each of those functions.
I already declared the variable as 'global' in the first function.
Should I declare this variable again and again as `global` in each function (and this will not overwrite the first `global` variable I declared in the first function) or I should not declare it again as `global` in all those functions (but the local variables there still will be seen as `global` since I already declared this variable so first time)?

Comment: The `global` keyword tells the parser **per function** that a name shouldn't be treated as a local when assigned to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so I should declare it as `global` in each function and the parser will understand that all these `global` variables are the same one?

Comment: **Normally** any name you bind in a function (assign to, use as a function argument, use in an `import` statement in the function body, etc.) is seen by the parser as a local. By using the `global` keyword, the parser will instead generate bytecode that'll look for a global name instead. If you have multiple functions that assign to the global, you'll need to declare that name `global` in all those functions. They'll then look up the name in the global namespace instead.

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters You could write this as an answer, not as a comment & I would give you all the points....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The global keyword tells the parser **per function** that a name shouldn't be treated as a local when assigned to.

**Normally** any name you bind in a function (assign to, use as a function argument, use in an import statement in the function body, etc.) is seen by the parser as a local.

By using the `global` keyword, the parser will instead generate bytecode that'll look for a global name instead. If you have multiple functions that assign to the global, you'll need to declare that name `global` in all those functions. They'll then look up the name in the global namespace instead.

See the [`global` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

> The `global` statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals.

and the [Naming and Binding documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding):

> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block. If a name is bound at the module level, it is a global variable. (The variables of the module code block are local and global.) If a variable is used in a code block but not defined there, it is a free variable.

Comment: thank you @Martijn Pieters. From the documentation above I would not be sure about all these. Now, after your explanations I understand this much better ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can declare a variable as `global` in each function definition. Here's an example:

```
def f():
    global x
    x = 2
    print x
    x +=2 
    # This will assign a new value to the global variable x

def g():
    global x
    print x
    x += 3
    # This will assign a new value to the global variable x

f()
# Prints 2
g()
# Prints 4
print x
# Prints 7
```

Comment: Ah, I think I understand it now. I've edited the answer to more directly answer your question.

Comment: Perfect... Saved my day.

Answer (score -2):

> Should I declare this variable again and again as global in each function

You should not have any global variables at all, and put these variables and functions into a class.

Comment: I think this is impossible in my code but I will take a thought in this direction

Comment: @Eliyahu It's not impossible in your code. It literally never is.

Comment: You are right but I currently prefer this way. It seems to me more suitable and easier in my circumstances.

Comment: @Eliyahu You're wrong. It's never more suitable, and you've already found the reason why it's more difficult to deal with global variables.